# Create list from values of one key of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, iteration

This is what my data looks like

```
[{'createdTime': '2017-11-05T06:43:08.000Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 14},
  'id': 'rec5Y5ML3w2nlKCYx'},
 {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T06:43:08.000Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 12},
  'id': 'recB8ioXO0c8f9AHc'},
 {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T07:26:51.915Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 17},
  'id': 'recCxg3XzjbQ1z5zh'}]
```

I need to extract the id values and put them in a simple list so the result should look like this.

```
['rec5Y5ML3w2nlKCYx','recB8ioXO0c8f9AHc','recCxg3XzjbQ1z5zh']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
data = [{'createdTime': '2017-11-05T06:43:08.000Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 14},
  'id': 'rec5Y5ML3w2nlKCYx'},
 {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T06:43:08.000Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 12},
  'id': 'recB8ioXO0c8f9AHc'},
 {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T07:26:51.915Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 17},
  'id': 'recCxg3XzjbQ1z5zh'}]
```

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[d['id'] for d in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
>>> lst=[{'createdTime': '2017-11-05T06:43:08.000Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 14},
  'id': 'rec5Y5ML3w2nlKCYx'},
 {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T06:43:08.000Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 12},
  'id': 'recB8ioXO0c8f9AHc'},
 {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T07:26:51.915Z',
  'fields': {'Pair ID': 17},
  'id': 'recCxg3XzjbQ1z5zh'}]

>>> [i.get('id') for i in lst]
['rec5Y5ML3w2nlKCYx', 'recB8ioXO0c8f9AHc', 'recCxg3XzjbQ1z5zh']
>>>
```